# "VideoCapture" does not contain a definiton for "GetCaptureProperty"

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am trying to follow a youtube tutorial on how I would be able to upload a video on a picture box using Emgu.Cv ([link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzIYD5QXTEk)) but I get this error :

```
Error   CS1061  'VideoCapture' does not contain a definition for 'GetCaptureProperty'
and no accessible extension method 'GetCaptureProperty' accepting a first argument of type 'VideoCapture' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    AutomatischerKamaramann C:\Users\49157\Desktop\Fixed project\grp09\programm\AutomatischerKamaramann\AutomatischerKamaramann\UserControl2.cs 55  Active
```

How can I fix it?

This is my code:

```
namespace AutomatischerKamaramann {
    public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl {
        VideoCapture videocapture;
        bool IsPlaying = false;
        int TotalFrames;
        int CurrentFrameNo;
        Mat CurrentFrame;
        int FPS;
        
        public UserControl2() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void iconButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {  // File path 
                string path = "";
                
                try {// Create open file dialog for opening input video 
           
                    OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog(); 
                    //Set the title for file dialog
                    fd.Title = "Bitte wählen Sie eine Videodatei ";
                    // Set the filter
                    fd.Filter = "MP4 Video (*.mp4)|*.mp4|WMV Video (*.wmv)|Quick Movie File (*.mov)|*.mov|";
                    //display the file dialog 
                    DialogResult status = fd.ShowDialog();
                    //Verify the whether user selects file or not using DialogRresult constant value 
                    if (status == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        videocapture = new VideoCapture(fd.FileName);
                        TotalFrames = Convert.ToInt32(videocapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameCount));
                        TotalFrames = Convert.ToInt32(videocapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameCount));
                        FPS = Convert.ToInt32(videocapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps));
                        IsPlaying = true;
                        CurrentFrame = new Mat();
                        CurrentFrameNo = 0;
                        trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
                        trackBar1.Maximum = TotalFrames - 1;
                        trackBar1.Value = 0;
                        Playvideo();

                        // Get the selected file path 
                        path = fd.FileName;
                        // set the selected imput file path to Textbox`"textbox1"
                        textBox1.Text = path;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`VideoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(...)` no longer exists.
Instead, try using `VideoCapture.Get(...)`
It's the same method, it just got renamed.

So in your case:

```
TotalFrames = Convert.ToInt32(videocapture.Get(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameCount));
FPS = Convert.ToInt32(videocapture.Get(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps));
```